# XLS0504 Property 'FontFamily' does not support values of type 'OnPlatform`1 (T)' Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, button, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

I'm trying to add `fontawsome` icons to my `Xamarin forms` project. I am following [this tutorial to do so](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U705QrGCHhs). However, when I use the following code,

```
<Button.FontFamily>
             <OnPlatform></OnPlatform>
</Button.FontFamily>
```

It shows an error. which is, `XLS0504 Property 'FontFamily' does not support values of type 'OnPlatform`1 (T)'`.

How can I resolve this error?

```
Xamarin Version - 5.0.0.2012
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's because you need to specify FontFamily as a String

Try something like the below:

```
<Button.FontFamily> 
   <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"> 
   <On Platform="iOS" Value="iOSFont" /> 
   <On Platform="Android" Value="AndroidFont" /> 
   <On Platform="UWP" Value="UWPFont" /> 
   </OnPlatform> 
</Button.FontFamily>
```

Good luck!